# Wait for page to finish loading & then random wait to show DIV

Tags: javascript

I would like to show my users popup like newsletter signup form. I want to use Javascript to wait for page finished loading and while they read after random wait (Minimum 10 seconds!) to show the div. And another small improvement if it's possible? (Only if it's not too hard to add a onmouseclick to hide div?)

Thanks a lot

Update got it to work to wait and load after 10 seconds. Need to add random wait

```
<body onLoad='setTimeout("showIt()", 10000);'>
    <body onLoad='setTimeout("showIt()", 10000);'>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showIt() {
          document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
        }
    // 1000 = 1 sec | 60000 is 1 minute
        </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than simply providing code to solve your problem, we prefer it if you show your attempts to solve the problem yourself, and we can guide you in the right direction. (TLDR: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party javascript framework?
Because much code can be spare (hooking up events etc.).
Basically what you want to do is hook an event to the dom's load event (in jquery its "ready"), in other frameworks there are other techniques.
Then setTimeout, with a (Math.random() * 20000 + 10000) for the time period. The time is in milliseconds, and I calculated a minimum value of 10 seconds, with additional range of 20 seconds, so 10+20 = maximum 30 seconds.

Comment: @daniel.gindi can you help me with the setTimeout I want to add to my function it's exactly what you're saying I need 10-60 seconds (10minimum)

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have succeeded in executing `showIt()` or the function is not even called or there is some problem with the div.style.display?

Comment: @tanmaykhandelwal it works now, Only thing is left random wait + some function to close it on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showIt() {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";

      setTimeout(closeIt, 10000);
    }

    function closeIt(){
       document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Edit:

```
<div id='myDiv' onclick='closeIt()'></div>
```

Edit:

```
<script>
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', callback, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', callback);
    }

    function callback(){
        setTimeout(showIt, (parseInt(Math.random()*(60000 - 10000)) + 10000));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I like the closeIt function it's what I need yeah, But not with setTimeout need to do it based on a click :)

Comment: perfect I will try and report back another thing I call showit using this code: <body onLoad='setTimeout("showIt()", 10000);'> I want to change the 10000 (10 seconds) to random from 10-60 seconds (And minimum 10 seconds) do you know how to add that?

Comment: what window.addeventlistener mean? <body onLoad='setTimeout("showIt()", (parseInt(Math.random()*(60000 - 10000)) + 10000)););'> should work?

Comment: Yes it should work. But it is good practice to add event listener in this way, because using `onload=function(){}` you are limiting your `window.onload` to have only one listener. In future, lets suppose, you want to add another listener to `window.onload`, you will not be able to do that using your method. So it's better to add another listener rather than directly using `onload='function(){}'`.
Further to make your page cross browser compatible, you should use both addEventListener as well as attachEvent. The attachEvent is supported in IE and addEventListener is supported in other browsers.